# Why does REQUEST_URI return "login.css.map", a file name that does not exist?

Tags: php, request-uri

My php sign-in controller stores the calling `REQUEST_URI` into a session variable and then validates the users credentials. Once validated the sign-in is marked and the script then does a `header('Location: /');` to re-direct back to my MVC entry point. My entry scheduler realises that a session variable has been created and uses it to execute the targeted controller.

On Chrome (Apple Mac), this all works fine. But within Safari, if I go to my home page to sign-in (/index.php), and sign-in. The `REQUEST_URI` contains "/assets/styles/login.css.map". The string "login.css" does not appear to exist anywhere within my framework, or at least my Mac can't find it. Any ideas, got me stumped?

Comment: .map files are source map files for css, so it looks as though it's making a request for this file and it's reaching your application instead of trying to load the file.

Comment: My .htaccess routes the request for a none existent file through my index.php, but I would love to know whats generating the request. I believe there is a bug in Safari whereby it requests commented out .map files where they are mentioned in javascript and have a preceding hash. Bootstap has this issue, but I can't find any reference to login.css anywhere. The fact that the request knows .css files are likely to be in /assets/styles/ suggests there just be a reference, I just can't find it!